# How to open file located inside winform project

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a project that requires some pdf reports to be opened from my forms. Since the program can be installed in any drive, I used the winform location directory as my path. I reports are located on a directory called Reports.  It works well under development becuase I the winform is under bin\debug, but when I deploy my solution and try the procedure, it does not work, the file cannot be found. I created a Reports directory after deployment, but still did not find my pdf.

Here is the code:

```
        'Open the requested file name. The files are stored in the
    'same path as the main workbook.
    '@param filename  file to be opened

    Function OpenReports(strFileName As String) As String

        Dim reportFolder As String

        Try

            reportFolder = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Reports")
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(reportFolder & "\" & strFileName)

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox("The " & strFileName & " is not found on directory")

        End Try

        Return strFileName

    End Function

Private Sub btnRptRangesToMarket_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRptRangesToMarket.Click

    'This procedure runs when the btnRptRangesToMarket is clicked
    'the procedure opens the pdf below by running the OpenReports Function

    OpenReports("Ranges to Market.pdf")

End Sub
```

Comment: What OS are you running on, you may be running into UAC issues. I usually put information like that in the ProgramData Directory instead of the Application Directory.

Comment: @MarkHall I am using Windows 8

Comment: *the file cannot be found. I created a Reports directory **after deployment**, but still did not find my pdf.* (How) Do you deploy the file??

Comment: @Chris I created the Reports folder and placed the folder under the Application directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Application.StartupPath` instead of `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`. I always get good results with that property.

This is from MSDN:

*The current directory is distinct from the original directory, which is the one from which the process was started.*